# Why do I get only Bool in my output and not the string also?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var timeRemaining = 10
var energy = 10
console.log("Game over:" + timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0);
```

Hello,
In the following I only get my output as true but my output is supposed to be Game Over: True?
Please help thank you.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq3n3.png)

I tried changing the qoutes or doing the Bool and a seperate line but I couldn't fix.

Comment: This works for me `console.log('Game over:', timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0)`

Comment: `console.log("Game over:" + (timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of operator precedence mean that:

```js
"Game over:" + timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0
```

is evaluated as:

```js
(("Game over:" + timeRemaining) == 0) || (energy == 0)
```

This means that `("Game over:" + timeRemaining) == 0` will never be true

Then, `(energy == 0)` will be false when `var energy = 10`, so the overall expression will evaluate as false.

You should instead write:

```js
"Game over:" + (timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0)
```

or

```js
`Game over: ${timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeRemaining = 10
var energy = 10
console.log("Game over:" + timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0);
```

First, operator precedence "+"

```js
"Game over:" + timeRemaining // "Game over:10"
```

Second, operator precedence  "=="

```js
"Game over:10" == 0 // false
```

Third, operator precedence  "=="

```js
energy == 0 // false
```

Lastly

```js
false || false // false
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more readable would be:

```js
var timeRemaining = 10
var energy = 10

console.log(`Game over: ${timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parenthesis around your conditions, otherwise this will get interpreted as follows:

First js does the string concatenation `"Game over:" + timeRemaining` => "Game over:10"

Then it checks if that string "Game over:10" equals 0, which it doesn't.

Then the other side of the || is evaluated. This also is not true, so the console log only prints false as a result of the conditions you put.

For it to work your line would look as follows:

`console.log("Game over: " + (timeRemaining == 0 || energy == 0));`

Does it make sense to log "Game over: false"?
If not I would change the line to something like:

`if (timeRemaining === 0 || energy === 0) console.log('Game Over!')`

These are some general tips for your javascript journey:

- Don't use `var` - use `let` or `const` instead. [check here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)
- decide whether or not you want to put semicolons, don't just switch from line to line.
- use strong comparison whenever you can (`===` over `==`).

Answer (score 0):

I added a new line in my console.log and it worked.
This is the part of code that passed

```js
// Implement getPrices()
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
    for (var item of dishData) {
        var finalPrice;
        if (taxBoolean===true) {
            finalPrice = item.price * tax;
        }
        else if (taxBoolean===false) {
            finalPrice = item.price;
        }
        else {
            console.log('You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!')
            return

        }
        console.log("\nDish:", item.name, "Price: $"+finalPrice); 

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).